# Можно ли использовать .php в шаблонах писем для рассылки?

Tags: php, html, база-данных, sendmail, outlook

Нужно сверстать шаблон письма для рассылки в outlook. Но раньше я этого не делал и толком не понимаю что да как, перечитал пару статей на эту тему и так и не понял, можно ли использовать .php в письме. Я бы хотел использовать php для подгрузки некоторых текстовых данных с базы данных сервера. Конкретно в тз смущает такое поле

> Жёлтые ячейки подлежат периодической замене, изменению ссылок и названий. Блок зелёных ячеек должен быть редактируемым, подлежащим постоянной замене, изменению ссылок, названий и картинок. Плюс ко всему, зелёный блок должен быть повторяющимся полностью: 1 зелёный блок = 1 акция, а их может быть несколько.

Т.е. речь идет о замене ссылок, названий и т.п. я не представляю как заказчик будет сам изменять нужное в .html файле, поэтому было бы легче сделать небольшую админку для этой работы. Приведу пример для большей ясности:
Можно ли в верстке письме для рассылки в outlook сделать такое:

```html
<table>
    <?php
        while ($categories = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            echo "<td>$catagories</td>";
    ?>
</table>
```

Вместо того чтобы делать такое:

```html
<table>
    <td>Категория 1<td>
    <td>Категория 2<td>
    <td>Категория 3<td>
</table>
```

*P.S. Или если php таки нельзя использовать, выходит что изменять содержимое письма можно только в самом файле `.html`?*

*P.S. Я вставляю файл с версткой в программе outlook 2016 через вложения->выбрать_файл->вставить как текст*

Comment: Речь про шаблон письма Outlook и отправка из Outlook?

Comment: @AndrewHobbit обычная табличная верстка письма